# PHP find same value in stdclass

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

i have an array with some stdclass inside

```
EventDates: [

   {
      Date: "1-5-2015 ",
      StartTime: "15:30 "
   },
   {
      Date: "1-5-2015 ",
      StartTime: "17:30 "
   },
   {
      Date: "2-5-2015 ",
      StartTime: "15:30 "
   },
   {
      Date: "2-5-2015 ",
      StartTime: "17:30 "
   },
   {
   {
      Date: "3-5-2015 ",
      StartTime: "15:30 "
   }
]
```

I want that the event witch have the same date to be display in one line, like:

Date: 1-5-2015

Time : 15:30  , 17:30

Date: 2-5-2015

Time : 15:30  , 17:30

Date: 3-5-2015

Time : 15:30

Comment: iterate the objects and compare the current's object's date to the previous one - if they are the same, print only the time. Otherwise, break the line and print the date and the time.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: actually i'm not very god in php , i've try with the foreach but no success. @OfirBaruch can you please write the code.

Comment: @ArditDine https://www.elance.com/

Comment: @OfirBaruch can you please help me